# Anniversary Edition: Do all Ornate Chests have a chance of being Majestic?

Tags: titan-quest-anniversary-edition

Do all Ornate Chests have a chance of being Majestic?

I've seen five-ish Ornate Chests repeatedly sometimes be a Majestic chest:

1. The one at the end of the cave used for the "Monstrous Brigands" quest, outside Helos.
2. The one on the undead-infested spur of land south of Sparta.
3. The one in the field right after Sparta.
4. The Ornate Chests inside the Fetid Lair in Tegea each have a chance to be Majestic instead.
5. The one in the Natural Cave on Megara Coast.

---

Comment: Downvote why? Bad formatting?

Comment: Second downvote why? Still bad formatting?